# CoCreateInstance takes a lot of time

Tags: com, regasm

After registering(RegAsm) my C# COM visible class, I see that `CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(myclass))` takes a lot of time only for the first time, subsequent attempts in the same client process are resolved instantly. Any idea why is it taking time?
NGen is not an option for me.

My COM Server is in C# and client is in MFC/ATL

```
CComPtr<namespace::Imyclass> obj;
hrx = obj.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(namespace::myclass));
```

Comment: What language/environment is your COM client written on?

Comment: What do you mean by "second time"?  The second time you call CoCreateInstance in the same client process?  Or the second time you start your client app it goes much faster?

Comment: @selbie send time in the same client process, if I restart my client it again has significant delay

Comment: Define "a lot of time". Minutes? Hours?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have seen delay upto 45 seconds

Answer (score 1):

The first call to `CoCreateInstance` has to load into the process, and initialize, the .NET runtime. Then, your DLL has to be loaded, "verified", and compiled into machine code (although just-in-time helps a lot to speed-up the startup). The .NET runtime also has to parse the metadata of your assembly, and then dynamically generate and compile the "COM callable wrappers" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07c8z1c.aspx) which are the proxies that bridge between the unmanaged COM world and the managed .NET runtime. Any additional libraries your code might use also needs to be loaded, verified and possibly compiled into machine code (if not NGEN'd).

This is inherently an expensive process. The delays you mention are not unheard of.

I don't believe there is much you can do to speed things up. I suggest you think about whether you can take the hit early in your program's lifetime by creating an object soon after startup. It won't make it faster, but it might improve the user experience dramatically. if your program just can't tolerate the delays, then you should not use .NET to write the COM object (more specifically, you should not use .NET in your process at all. This is not an issue with using COM; it's an issue with loading .NET)

Incidentally, this is one of the reasons why writing shell extensions in .NET is... "highly discouraged". See this recent post on this subject, which touches on the startup performance of .NET as well: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/22/10396079.aspx

(That's why I asked earlier what kind of client you were running. A client that already runs .NET managed code depends on the .NET runtime and would not be affected by these delays)

Comment: And yet... Although I have seen 45 delays, I have to admit that 45 seconds is a bit stiff, unless the machine is fairly underpowered or overloaded. You don't indicate what kind of machine and load are we talking about. Also, are you measuring this delay while debugging? That could make a huge difference in startup time.

Answer (score 0):

The first call to `CoCreateInstance` is likely having to consult the registry and the file system, loading the appropriate code, allowing it to initialize, and finally invoke a factory to create the instance you've asked for (if it could be located).

The second call benefits hugely from these previous steps. If the first call was successful, then the code is already loaded and initialized, and all it has to do is invoke a factory a second time.

Answer (score 0):

If this delay is only for first load *(after computer start)*, then this is caused by loading all libraries. First delay after start *(or after long time without usage of .NET)* will always be slow. (See Micelli answer)

Delay can be also caused on each loading. Today I found out that internet connection can also cause the delay.

Measured values:

1. No Ethernet and no WiFi connection delay: 94 ms (Win7) / 1.5 (WinXP)
2. Windows XP: Internet connection *(with proxy and non standard gateway; not all ports are allowed)*:  4-5 s (WinXP)
3. Connected to Ethernet not not to Internet: 10 s (Win7)
4. Short after the connection to Ethernet *(Windows test Internet connection; blue circle on the Network Icon)*: 30 s (Win7)
5. Internet connection *(with proxy and non standard gateway; only few ports are allowed)*:  30 s (Win7)

*non standard gateway: allowed TCP ports and connections are different for each computer (Different for WinXP and Win7).

Tested on Windows 7 (x64) and WinXP. I tested it because it came as a complain from a customer and located the delay to **CoCreateInstance** The loaded library is in c# and is signed *(signed assembly with snk and with standard certificate for signing executable files)*.

See also: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cda45e39-ed11-4a17-a922-e47aa2e7b325/ce-40-delay-when-cocreateinstance-on-pc-without-internet?forum=sqlce